# why there is a spike in my profiler when i click the button for the first time?

Tags: c#, optimization, unity-game-engine, profiler

In my game I am trying to increase/decrease power and angle of projection of ball through script,
everything is working fine, there is no lag , but when i first click on a button to increase power there is a huge spike in my profiler , after that when i click for the second time there is no huge spike
here is my code

```
    void FixedUpdate () {
    aimAngle.z = increaseAngle;
    aim.transform.eulerAngles = aimAngle;

    if (Input.GetButton ("Fire1")) {
        IncreaseDecreaseAngleOfAimOrPower ();
    }
    if (Mathf.Abs( rigidBody.velocity.x) <= 0.8f && Mathf.Abs( rigidBody.velocity.x) > 0 && rigidBody.velocity.y  <=0.0f) {
        rigidBody.angularDrag = 5.0f;
    }

}

void IncreaseDecreaseAngleOfAimOrPower(){

    collider_1 = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition),Vector3.forward,1.0f);
    if (collider_1) {
        if (collider_1.transform.CompareTag("IncreaseAngle")) {
            increaseAngle += Time.deltaTime * 25;
        } else if (collider_1.transform.CompareTag( "DecreaseAngle")) {
            increaseAngle -= Time.deltaTime * 25;
        } else if (collider_1.transform.CompareTag ( "PowerIncrease")) {
            power += Time.deltaTime * 25;
        } else if (collider_1.transform.CompareTag ("PowerDecrease")) {
            power -= Time.deltaTime * 25;
        } else if (collider_1.transform.CompareTag ( "Shoot") && shoot) {
            forceAngle.x = Mathf.Cos (aimAngle.z * Mathf.PI / 180);
            forceAngle.y = Mathf.Sin (aimAngle.z * Mathf.PI / 180);
            rigidBody.isKinematic = false;
            rigidBody.AddForce ( (forceAngle * power),ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            aim.gameObject.SetActive (false);
            shoot = false;
        }
    } 

}
```

here is the screenshot when i clicked for the first time
[image]

here is the screenshot when i clicked for the second time
[image]

Comment: Because of `Ball.IncreaaseDecreaseAngleblablabla`, which is not called second time?

Comment: no it is called every fixed update when i click on the button

Comment: Maybe because of .NET? CLR compiles your bytecode into native code during first call since start and later it uses cached version. 

i suppose unity doing extra work on first call of physics2d.raycast.

I would recomend to track execution time(use Stopwatch class) of this functions into your log.

Comment: +1 Andrey and there's also lazy binding, caching, etc. As long as the game runs smooth, don't worry about it. If something really is messed up and you are sure your code is optimal, as well as hardware is reasonably strong, cache/configure/etc before use.

Comment: hey Andrey probably you are write it takes some time to load the method (Ball.IncreaaseDecreaseAngleblablabla)  initially and later it uses its cached version

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of JIT compilation. When you call IncreaseDecreaseAngleOfAimOrPower() for the first time the compiler may need to compile the code for some related methods. In your case it's probably the `Raycast(...)`.

This makes your application freeze for some time. When calling the method for the next times, it's already compiled and does not freeze.